# shell script replace and add next line with special characters

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, sed

I am trying replace a line with another line and add new line below that using a shell script.

I want to replace:

```
export PATH
```

with:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-ibm-1.8.0.2.10-1jpp.1.el7.x86_64
export PATH JAVA_HOME
```

That means, it has to replace replace `export PATH` with these two lines.

Please help me how can I do with sed or shell script

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36756111/1030675

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's|^export PATH$|JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-ibm-1.8.0.2.10-1jpp.1.el7.x86_64\
& JAVA_HOME|' < "$yourfile"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use sed command :

```
sed -i 's/<original text>/<new-text>/g' file.txt


sed -i 's/original/new/g' file.txt
```

Explanation:

- sed = Stream EDitor
- -i = in-place (i.e. save back to the original file) The command string:
- s = the substitute command
- original text = a regular expression describing the word to replace (or
  just the word itself)
- new text = the text to replace it with
- g = global (i.e. replace all and not just the first occurrence)
- file.txt = the file name

Alternative :

```
awk '{gsub(/'pattern'/,"replacement")}' file
```